# Migrate your App Profile Page

Tags: facebook, profile, migrate

My question concerns this blog post: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/01/how-to--migrate-your-app-profile-page/

I saw the message on the App Profile Page: http://www.facebook.com/streema , but as I couldn't migrate them to a Page, I didn't do it - probably because we didn't have exactly the same name. I think that wasn't clear enough though.

Besides, it was important for us to preserve our vanity URL, and as I didn't read about that issue in any place, I decided to don't make the change yet.

We have over 16K likes on our App, I think it would be a shame to loose them all.

Hope someone can help us. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The migration was available from 10 December 2011 until 7 February 2012 and was announced in several blog posts and via a message at the top of all app profile pages during the migration period. 
Apps created after 10 December 2011 never had an App Profile Page to be migrated, but apps created before this had the option to migrate. 
The migration option is no longer available - if you want a page for your app you need to create a new page from the app's settings interface